# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) in Xcode Error

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I am writing some code that solves a crossword puzzle in the form of a text file. Parsing the file and creating the crossword of type `vector<vector<char>>` works correctly. I am encountering a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` error in the `horizontal_forward_search` function, upon indexing the crossword, `crossword[row_num][col_num]`.

```
pair<int, int> iterate(vector<vector<char>> crossword, string word) {
    int row_num = 0;

    for (vector<char> row: crossword) {
        ++row_num;
        int col_num = 0;
        for (char letter: row) {
            ++col_num;
            if (letter == word[0]) {  // first letter of word found, confirm/deny word
                pair<int, int> location = horizontal_forward_search(crossword, row_num, col_num, word);
                if (location.first != -1)
                    return location;

            }
        }
    }
    return make_pair(-1, -1);
}
```

and

```
pair<int, int> horizontal_forward_search(vector<vector<char>> crossword, int row_num, int col_num, string word) {
    long remaining_chars = crossword[row_num].size() - col_num;

    if (word.size() > remaining_chars)   // word size exceeds remaining characters
        return make_pair(-1, -1);

    else {
        string temp_str = "";
        int cur_pos = col_num;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < word.size()) {
            char cur_letter = crossword[row_num][col_num];  // Error here
            temp_str.push_back(cur_letter);
            ++cur_pos;  // next pos in array
            ++i;
        }
        if (temp_str == word)
            return make_pair(row_num, col_num);
    }
    return make_pair(-1,-1);

}
```

I know there are several ways to debug this instrumentally, but the code is straight forward. In the `iterate` function, `crossword` is copied over to `crossword` within the `horizontal_forward_search` function, ideally giving access to the crossword. Yet, upon doing `crossword[row_num][col_num]`, I am met with an error.

Comment: Are `row_num` and `col_num` within bounds of the vectors? Somehow I doubt that since your algorithm will use *one-based* indexing instead of zero-based.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should learn about passing function arguments by reference. More specifically you should pass `crossword` as a constant reference (`vector<vector<char>> const& crossword`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nope. Don't know how I missed that. Thank you. I was passing it in as a reference before, thinking that was causing the issue. I will change it.